# Heroku deployment error: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, express, angularfire

I am trying to deploy my AngularJS Yeoman Generator-AngularFire Node Express app to Heroku. I am able to push to Heroku successfully as it shows

```
Fetching repository, done.
Everything up-to-date
```

when I `git push heroku master`

(Not completely sure if this means it is failsafe, tip to check another way would be much appreciated). When I run the command `heroku open` my web page shows

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I ran the command `heroku logs` I get these errors:

```
2014-09-27T21:25:11.216896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mayapp.herokuapp.com request_id=6921ca4b-13de-4194-858f-0132a0d36192 fwd="70.166.121.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-09-27T21:25:11.712742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=6e6dde3a-ca2a-4650-95c0-c4ad68d7f597 fwd="70.166.121.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here are my routes in my routes.js

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })

  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}])
```

How do I get passed this issue and successfully deploy?

Comment: This doesn't look like it's going to be a JavaScript/Angular problem--that would not crash your Heroku worker. It's the Heroku router that's failing (with a 503 status code), not your in-page js router after it's served to the client's browser and compiled to run.

Comment: Realized how much easier it is to just host through Firebase - https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/